# Webpack: use fs with npm package, but not in browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, webpack, bundling-and-minification

I'm developing a library with Webpack that needs to work in the browser and in a Node.js environment. There is only one function which needs fs, a function that would only be called in a Node environment (it's to add compatibility with Express). I've added:

`target: 'node',
externals: {
  fs: 'commonjs fs'
}`

However, the webpack build process still throws an error.

What can I do to make it so that I can use `fs`?

Answer (score 0):

Found solution! Put `var fs = require('fs')` inside of your function that uses it.